# clearfix to views-row

Tags: views, theming

What is the recommended way to add a "clearfix" class to a `div.views-row`?

Note that I dont want to add the clearfix to all views, just a specific view.

Is this best done with a template override, or is there a mystical alter hook that will let me add in what I need in my `template.php` without having to override and thus maintain an entire views template file, just to add a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this views 3? If so if you go to the Settings for the format you can add a Row class (the description says "The class to provide on each row") which should do what you want without templates etc.

Comment: It is indeed Views 3, and this works perfectly! Thanks Malks, you learn something new (about views) everyday.